# Asynchronous Javascript callback never occure in my Angular 4.0 app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback

I'm trying to use this https://github.com/masterT/bandcamp-scraper in my Angular application. 
https://github.com/JanneHarju/MultiSourcePlayList/blob/master/angular2App/app/modules/searchlist/searchlist.component.ts#L106
Here is example how it should be used:

```
var bandcamp = require('bandcamp-scraper');
var params = {
  query: 'Men I Trust',
  page: 1
};
bandcamp.search(params, function(error, searchResults) {
   if (error)
   {
       console.log(error);
   }
   else
   {
       console.log(searchResults);
   }
});
```

The problem is that callback never occure.
I also tried wrap the call with Promise like this.

```
doBandcampCall(q: Object) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        bandcamp.search(q, function(err:any, result:any) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

But it doesn't affect to result.
This Bandcamp-scraper uses tinyreq which make the actual http request.

There is't any errors when this is called.

Is there something I should know about asynchronous javascript calls in Angular.

Comment: https://npm.runkit.com/bandcamp-scraper Here you can test bandcamp-scraper end ti works like a charm

Comment: Does anybody has even a guess that I can try?